# Virtual Machine for Linux partition error: VERR_SHARING_VIOLATION

Tags: boot, windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a SSD HD with two partitions, one for Windows 10 and another for Linux mint. I am trying to create a vmdk to boot my Linux on a VM running in my Windows 10, but I am getting this error: "***Cannot open the raw disk '\.\PhysicalDrive0': VERR_SHARING_VIOLATION***"; when I try to run this command on Windows:

```
VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename C:\Users\mucida\Desktop\ubuntu.vmdk -rawdisk \\.\PhysicalDrive0
```

All solutuions that I have found so far seems to be for those who have two HD (not just one with partitions)

Any help?

Comment: First, this is a Windows problem, not Linux. Second, have you tried the solutions you found? There is no fundamental difference between partition and disk.

Comment: I tried, but they ask to stop some programs that are running on that physicalDrive ... but this pyshical drive is the only one, and I cant stoip thinmgs listed like "system". The drive will be always being used. I tried with the "partitions" argument in front of the command, but it gives the same error

Comment: The problem is `-rawdisk \\.\PhysicalDrive0`. I guess you can't use the Windows disk in a virtual machine. Try the `-partitions` parameter.